# How using both functions to listen data on Firebase- Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data on Firebase like this:

```
"node": {
   "node1": {
      "value1": value,
      "value2": value,
      "subSubNode":{
          //....values....//
       },
   },

"node2": { ... },
  "node3": { ... }
  //...and so on ..//
}
```

*First:* I want to get all data from Firebase and render to my tree so I used **addListenerForSingleValueEvent()** function.

*Then:* I used **addChildEventListener()** function to listen when a node or child change, remove or added...

```
private void getData(Query ref){
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            **I render data on my tree here**
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onChildAdded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onChildChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onChildRemoved");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onChildMoved");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled");
        }
    });
}
```

But **onChildAdded()** method in **addChildEventListener()** function is always run first. Any idea or solution for me? Do I use **addChildEventListener()** function on that position correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods in `ChildEventListener` fire for both initial data *and* for subsequent changes to that data.

Once you call `addChildEventListener()`, you will get a call to `onChildAdded()` for each existing child node. You can use these event to build the initial tree. After the initial data has been added, you will receive a calls to all `onChild...` methods as the data changes.

So don't register for `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` and simply build the tree from the methods of `ChildEventListener`.

*Alternatively* if you want to separately handle the initial data, you can make use of one of the [event guarantees that Firebase has](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-guarantees):

> Value events are always triggered last and are guaranteed to contain updates from any other events which occurred before that snapshot was taken.

```
boolean isInitialValueLoaded = false;
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        **I render data on my tree here**
        isInitialValueLoaded = true;
    }

    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
});

ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        if (!isInitialValueLoaded) return;
        Log.i(TAG, "onChildAdded");
    }

    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        if (!isInitialValueLoaded) return;
        Log.i(TAG, "onChildChanged");
    }

    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (!isInitialValueLoaded) return;
        Log.i(TAG, "onChildRemoved");
    }

    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        if (!isInitialValueLoaded) return;
        Log.i(TAG, "onChildMoved");
    }

    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled");
    }
});
```